# Flask requests.args keep variable in new app route

Tags: flask, jinja2, forms

i am getting a variable using request.args. I would like to add another app route to obtain a new variable that will link to the client_id in the app route '/search/'.  how do i keep this client_id variable when adding another app route?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)
import pandas as pd


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    res = '''<form action="/search" method=>
                    <p><input type="text" name="query" value="test"></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
                    <br />
    </form>'''
    return res 

@app.route('/search', methods=["GET","POST"])
def suggestion():
    client_id = request.args['query']  
    return render_template('untitled2.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

for example, I want to add this app route

```
@app.route('/csv/')
def download_csv():
    #can't figure out how to obtain the client_id var
    client_id = ??? 
    model_id=request.args['textid']
    model_id1=request.args['textid1']
    model_id2=request.args['textid2']

    # return response
    df=recommender.update_history(client_id, model_id, model_id1, model_id2)
    df= recommender.get_csv()
    resp = make_response(df.to_csv(encoding='iso-8859-1',index=False))
    resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
    return resp
```

here's what I have on my html template where i need to grab the variable that was formerly in request.args['text'] and send it to the new app route "/csv" along with the new form data:

untitled2.html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Suggestions for {{ request.args['text']  }}  </h4>
            <form action ="/csv">
             <form method="POST">
                <br>
                <label>Enter 3 suggestions</label>
                <br>
                <input name="textid", placeholder="Suggested Model ID #", value="{{ request.form['textid'] }}"/>
                <input name="textid1", placeholder="Suggested Model ID #", value="{{ request.form['textid1'] }}"/>
                <input name="textid2", placeholder="Suggested Model ID #", value="{{ request.form['textid2'] }}"/>

                <input type="submit" >
              </form>
          </div>

 <h4>Entered Suggestions:{{ request.form['textid'] }}  {{ request.form['textid1'] }}  {{ request.form['textid2'] }} </h4>
```

Comment: In html file, you are using request.args['text'], but in app.py you use `client_id = request.args['query']`... mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your `client_id` variable, by adding it to session, save it in cookie or 
 use `g`object.

For session, just use instead of `client_id`, `session['client_id'] = request.args['query']`. You can always get it with `session['client_id']` . Additionally, you must set secret key in config of app like so `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'My secret key'`.

Read more about sessions [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-secure-is-the-flask-user-session).